# Avoiding button action based on a condition

Tags: button

I have a button on Opportunity Page (button created and added by layout, normally), that perform an action. I'd like to do a check before this action is performed, based on the value of a field of the record on which I'm pressing the button. So if the Field A has not a particular value, the button should return an error message and not perform any action. How can I accomplish this requirement (javascript?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your button one that invokes JavaScript (see e.g. [Creating a Button with Apex](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-button-with-apex)), you can include values from the current page in the JavaScript:

```
var condition = '{!Opportunity.FieldA}' == 'Particular Value';
if (condition) {
    var result = sforce.apex.execute(...);
    ...
} else {
    alert('Wasn\'t the right value');
}
```

Alternatively you can perform the check in the Apex code that is executed and return the message from there.

Comment: are you sure is it correct that syntax? I can make it work if I reference a field of a VF page by its Id and using $Component with getElementById, but I can make it work with fields of a standard page (so with your solution)

Comment: @toninotrip There was one mistake that I've just edited that the embedded quote wasn't escaped but otherwise yes. If you use your browser's "View Page Source" and search for "invokeOnClickJS" you will see the generated code (an `eval` of a string) and what `{!Opportunity.FieldA}` expands too: it should just be the value of the field. If the value isn't a string you'll also have to do the appropriate formatting.